# initialization discards qualifiers... sdl warning

Tags: c, sdl

When I run this bit of code through GCC I get this warning on the line where I set info to SDL_GetVideoInfo().

warning: initialization discards qualifiers from pointer target type

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);

    SDL_VideoInfo* info = SDL_GetVideoInfo();
    int SCREEN_WIDTH = info->current_w;
    int SCREEN_HEIGHT = info->current_h;
    printf("hardware acceleration? %s\n", info->hw_available == 1 ? "yes" : "no");
    printf("memory available in kilobytes: %d\n", info->video_mem);
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Does anyone know how I can change the code so I can get around that warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could `SDL_GetVideoInfo` be returning a pointer to a `const SDL_VideoInfo` ?

---

*[2 minutes and a google search later]*

The declaration of `SDL_GetVideoInfo` I found online is:

```
const SDL_VideoInfo* SDL_GetVideoInfo(void);
```

Indeed it returns a const pointer which you convert to a non-const pointer, hence the warning. Note that you shouldn't just ignore it, since when the function wants to return a const pointer it frequently has a good reason for it - it probably doesn't make sense, or is even harmful, to modify the returned object through the pointer.

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_GetVideoInfo) says that the function returns a `const SDL_VideoInfo *`, so change your code to:

```
const SDL_VideoInfo* info = SDL_GetVideoInfo();
```

Without the `const`, `info` could be used to change the value pointed to by it, but obviously, you can't do that.